# Paypal Credit Card Not Showing

Tags: wordpress, paypal, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use woocommerce paypal for australia country but its not showing credit card option in website for payment.How can i show crdit card option for make payment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of steps to set Paypal with credit card option in your site.

First of all, you need to install `WooCommerce PayPal Express Checkout` plugin.

Then  Go to WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout> PayPal Express Checkout and Enable PayPal Express Checkout option there.

Now, these plugin has a feature to make payment using credit card also. for that, you just need to the option to use PayPal Credit in checkout, if the checkbox for Enable PayPal Credit is ticked in Display Settings from Setup and Configuration.

See [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/) link for more details.

Hope this will helpful for you.

Thanks.